# Update TextBox after a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox id="locSelectedCameraGroupName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I have this back end code:

```
protected void btnCameraGroup_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    locSelectedCameraGroupName.Text = "test string!";
}
```

This method is called after clicking a button:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="btnCameraGroup" runat="server" onclick="btnCameraGroup_ServerClick" onclientclick="ShowCameraGroupPopup()"
    style="font-size: 1.2em; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; background-color:grey; "> 
<!-- TODO:  Make button have round corners...css? -->
</asp:linkbutton>
```

However, the text does not update.  This is a user control.  The line is reached (according to my debugger).  When I move the line to my page load, it works.  Is there something wrong I am doing?

The following method `ShowCameraGroupPopup` just shows/hides some tags  I don't think it has much to do with the issue, but here it is anyways:

```
function ShowCameraGroupPopup() {
    $('#<%=waitIcon.ClientID%>').show();
    $('#<%=divMainContent.ClientID%>').hide();
    $("#divCameraGroupPopup").modal("show");
    return true;
}
```

This is the flow after clicking the link button:

1. Page_Load hit (is post back)
2. btnCameraGroup_ServerClick hit
3. Tab name = Second tab (this is the info I want, but for some reason the
   text isn't updated)

Comment: Is click handler being called? can u put a breakpoint there and see if value is being assigned?

Comment: What happens in your "ShowCameraGroupPopup"? could that block calls to server? Try removing that onclienclick or return true from it.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter The `btnCameraGroup_ServerClick` method is being called according to my debugger.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The `ShowCameraGroupPopup` is just a javascript method that shows/hides other dividers in the page.

Comment: Also, to the downvoter, please explain your downvote

Comment: Also, to the close voter, the problem is clear and concise.  I explain what results I expect and what I actually get.  I give relative minimal code.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I even added a print statement and it prints the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed an UpdatePanel (and ContentTemplate) around the TextBox with a Triggers (AsyncPostBackTrigger) as so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="groupNamePanel" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional"> 
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCameraGroup" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="locSelectedCameraGroupName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you have Page_Load() event in your codes, change Page_Load() content like below:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //copy previous page load codes here
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I want to be able to do it via other method (not page load).