# How to set html input type text value using ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, html, client-side, server-side

I have an html control which I want to set its value ....
here's the control:

```
<input runat="server" id="first_name_txt" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
```

in code behind, I use:

```
first_name_txt.Value = String.empty;
```

but the value of my input control still has the old value like "blah-blah" and not set to "".

Comment: I don't get how the value `blah-blah` got there. I think you are not showing / telling us all.

Comment: **if you used pageload event, see this question [answere][1]**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918391/update-textbox-after-a-button-click/24919179#24919179

Comment: As @PatrickHofman, stated, show us where the input value is first set to `blah-blah`

Comment: It's a registration form, and I want to clear the input of first name after clicking button "submit".
If I wrote "Andrew" in this input field and pressed "submit", I want the input value to be cleared.

Answer (score 4):

Its old question , but may help someone.

You have to use **Request.Form** to get and call **.Value**  to set the value.

**HTML**

```
 <input runat="server" id="first_name_txt" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
    //To get value:
    string myname=Request.Form["first_name_txt"];

   // To set value:
    first_name_txt.Value="";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<td>
  <input type="text" name="date" value="<%= tdate %>" />
</td>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected string tdate { get; set; }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.tdate = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: it is working now after I add this control in an update panel

Comment: @Andrew_Nady if this answer helped you please greenmark it.

Comment: I think you wanted to edit your original answer but posted another one instead by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**Hello it's not that easy to set data into HTML input, but here is a link that may help you** [[Link]](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/264559/request-form-value-to-get-and-to-set-).

1) If it didn't work up to you try to set a **value** and calling it through **Javascript** and set the **text** of this input like the gotten **value**.

2) You can use the [Div] tag using runat="server", clear it and create a new input with same id,name,etc. but different **Text value**

Try Step 2 as follow(it worked):

```
   <div id="divTitle" runat="server">
               <input type="text" class="input_Text" id="Title"  name="Title"  /> 
   </div> 

divTitle.Controls.Clear();
divTitle.InnerHtml = "<input type='text' class='input_Text' id='Title'  name='Title' value='" + ds(0)("Title").ToString() + "' />";
```

> Where ds is a data table that came from select query from database

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           first_name_txt.Value = String.empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

here is very simple way to do this
 { text_Box.Value = "data";}