# Is there a way to reference a asp ID using a variable in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use a c# variable to remove an attribute.

I am testing my approach before actually coding application.

I've tried javascript and jQuery but found nothing that would allow to
substitute TextBox ID with value of string in codebehind.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="myText" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page 
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string straspID = "myText";


            bool fieldRequired = false;

            if (fieldRequired == false)
            {

                //FindControl("myText");
                FindControl(straspID);
                if (straspID != null)
           //         
                myText.Attributes.Remove("required");
          // I want to use straspID instead of the ID of the asp page
          // which will returned from a table - I'm simulating here
          // I get an error if I use straspID for remove attribute 
            }


        }

    }
}
```

My expected result is to remove the attribute for selected ID.
I am currently getting a syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried using `myText`? Why do you want to use a string instead?

Comment: I will be getting the value form a table which will contain asp ID's

Comment: mytext works but I won't know the value of the tag in the real world

Comment: My advice is don't use web forms... its practically useless and considered legacy at this point...use.net core mvc or web api. Anyway, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759219/8167494, it may help

Comment: Referring to it as useless is a bit of a stretch @IsaacVidrine.

Comment: @mjwills okay yeah it was. Its definitely not useless but there are **much** better technologies out there you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
            FindControl(straspID);
```

is not doing what you think it is.

Can you check your index.aspx.designer.cs file and see if there is a protected member variable called 'myText' ?

If there is, you can simply do this: -

```
        if (fieldRequired == false)
        {
            myText.Attributes.Remove("required");
        }
```

If there is no protected member called myText, add one at class level to 'index': -

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page 
    {
        protected Textbox myText;

        (etc)
```

As long as you declare it of the correct type and with the same name and casing, there is no need to resort to FindControl to access a server control.

Comment: Looked.  Yes it is . I have to find a way to use the variable because the values will be coming from a list created from a sql table.  Will a struct help?

Answer (score 0):

private void loadform(List providerList)
        {
            foreach (ProviderInRequest req in providerList)
            {
                // taget div for plan
                Control ctrl = FindControl("div" + req.aspName);
                // set visible to true if we found it.
                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    //set div to visible
                    ctrl.Visible = true;

```
                // set label to proper text
                Label lbl = (Label)Page.FindControl("lbl" + req.aspName);
                lbl.Text = displayName;
```